# PHP mySQLi: if "&&" protocol and mySQLi statement error checking

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm implementing some basic getter functions using mysqli and was thinking of a way to be lazy in error checking, but still correct.

So I wrote this type of code segment

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username) && !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) && !mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt) && !mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result) && !mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    //Error Protocol
}
```

I've read that PHP is lazy in checking its ANDs and just checks until the first failure. Since mysqli_stmt_error also returns the most recent error, I thought this type of structure would work well. However, I am not sure if there is something that I'm not thinking of that could compromise this type structure.

Comment: it'll work, but consider legibility down the road. any code which has 2/3rd of the statement off-screen is probably going to earn you some nastygrams when someone else takes over maintenance of the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Woops, I had it backwards, the combination of "!" and "&&" meant that the first successful mysqli_stmt method would end the if statement because of the "!". So, I changed the "&&" to "||" this way, the first false statement would be flipped to true and trigger the if statement.

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username) 
    || !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) 
    || !mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt) 
    || !mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result) 
    || !mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    //Error Protocol
}
//Success Protocol
```

If I wanted to implement it using the "&&", I'd have to drop the "!"

```
if(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username) 
    && mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) 
    && mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt) 
    && mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result) 
    && mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    //Success Protocol
}
//Error Protocol
```